# How to link the residential buildings and residential in osm?

Tags: openstreetmap

In osm. I can map building  with tag building = residential 
also can map Residential way with tag landuse = residential
but how to map The building belongs to residential?
I thought of a way  map the building with operator = 'xxxx'. But it does not seem right

Comment: cross-post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/56490/how-to-link-the-residential-buildings-and-residential-in-osm

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would expand your buildings tags to include not just 'residential' but also other appropriate tags like 'apartments', 'house', 'detached' etc (see OSM [documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:building)) as these are also indicators of a building being residential.

To link buildings to roads and areas, you could do a [spatial join](http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/joins.html) of buildings to residential areas ([landuse=residential](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:landuse)) or residential roads (e.g. highway='residential' don't forget the other residential-type [tags for roads](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway) like 'living_street'). There is also another tag that might prove useful and that is '[abutters](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:abutters)'.  This specifically describes the buildings beside the road.  However, I am not sure how widespread the use of this tag is so a little investigation in your area of interest would be advisable.

In any of these options, if your purpose is just a visual map, then an appropriate solution may be as simple as applying a distinctive style to the residential areas or roads and then a user of your map can infer that the buildings there are residential (in this scenario you would not need to even do the spatial join).  In this scenario, you may want to mark specifically non-residential buildings (commercial, place_of_worship etc).

Comment: The abutters tag isn't really in use any more, better avoid it.

Comment: spatial join  is the responsibility of the search engine, does not  osm tag have this semantic expression?

Comment: Why? The buildings are already contained in the landuse area. An additional tag is not needed and would be redundant.

Comment: @scai  in overpass ,  i can find building entrance very simply because a entrance node is a subnode from a building ,  , and find admin subarea  and find traffic signal in highway and so on .. why i need spatial join for find  buildings in residential?

Comment: and I remember that overpass does not support polygon queries

Comment: This depends on the specific case. Overpass API supports area queries but only if these areas have a name. You can set up your own Overpass API instance without this limitation. However this doesn't belong here, ask a new question instead. Also, it isn't the goal of tags to solve spatial tasks. These things are not part of the data model and have to be solved by the end user.